# Nusphere PHPEd: PHP Function Hints Lost Arguments?

Tags: php, ide, phped

My PHPEd suddenly stopped showing arguments and arg order in the hints, and now just shows a basic description of the function.

Before I go digging around in the config files, has anyone else had this problem?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

Sorry, I may not have been entirely clear on this.  There is no problem with my own classes, only with the actual php functions.

Example:

How it used to work:

I type a PHP function, say strpos.  As soon as I type the '(' at the end of it, I get the little yellow box, showing something like this:

```
int strpos  ( string $haystack  , mixed $needle  [, int $offset=0  ] )
```

with the first argument bold.  If I type it, and then a comma, it bolds the second arg, and so on.  This is really nice, since PHP functions are a bit scrambled as far as argument order, and I don't have to look them up every time.

How it works now:

I type a php function, say strpos.  As soon as I type the '(' at the end of it, I get the little yellow box.  It says something like "strpos - Returns the numeric position of the first occurrence of needle  in the haystack  string."

There are no arguments shown, which makes the little box basically worthless - I know what strpos does, I just want a reminder of the argument order.

I think this may be a problem with the included PHPDoc, which I never use, but may be the source of the data for the hint box.

I did recently upgrade to 5.6, but ended up removing it and restoring 5.2.  I installed to a different folder, and uninstalled from there, but it may have overwritten something in the original folder?

I'm using v5.2 (5220).

Comment: Your final edit should actually be posted as the answer to the question. Then it can be upvoted as others find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

What version of PhpEd are you using ? And did you made an update of PhpEd recently ?

As mentionned in the [forum](http://forum.nusphere.com/viewtopic.php?t=1906&highlight=hints), that can modify the "Function Arguments Tooltip" feature behavior.

One way to check if this is linked to settings is to move the `phped.cfg`config file (save it), and let PhpEd recreates it with default values. If that does restore the tooltips, use a diff program to check what option may have been changed.

Do you see no hints for *all* classes, or only your own Php classes (in the latter case, [this thread](http://forum.nusphere.com/viewtopic.php?t=3153&highlight=hints) has some setting advices) ?

---

Note: the reason I ask for the version is because of [this very recent thread](http://forum.nusphere.com/viewtopic.php?t=5661&highlight=function+argument+tooltip), about PhpEd5.5:

[image]

In that case, the advice is to **copy `%PROGRAMFILES%\nusphere\phped\config\func.rel` into `%APPDATA%\nusphere\phped\config\` directory overriding the file in it.**

Answer (score 0):

A complete re-install seems to have done fixed the problem. Perhaps it was a problem with a partial upgrade or a version mismatch on the settings.